# Crashing on calling virtual methods

Tags: c++

I read about it in other questions but none of them was similar, some was about to call a virtual method in the constructor, others about pure virtuals, but the question here is about vituais methods that are not pure, but about virtual methods that doesn't need be implemented in all derivatives classes. If the class instantiated doesn't implements the method, if we call, it logically calls the method from the base and it crashes sometimes.
I was wondering, why? What is VTABLE (where it enters)? And what is the best way to solve it.

This is a simple example, (avoid answer like pure virtual).

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    virtual std::string myString() {}
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    Foo * bar = new Foo;
    bar->myString();

    return 0;
}
```

What would be the best solution?

1. Throw an exception
2. Using assert(false)
3. Returning a default value
4. Avoid implementing a body and it will result in an error in
   compilation time
5. None of the alternatives

The best answer will be the one that explains why this happen based on VTABLE and of course, that choose one solution and explain why. The idea is not to base it on opinions.

Comment: This example doesn't crash, does it? Show one which does. Edit: Oh my, it does. I'm baffled.

Comment: what do you mean by "best solution" ?

Comment: @PeterSchneider - Here, at least it does.

Comment: Oh, the function doesn't return anything. Unrelated to virtual problem.

Comment: @StephaneRolland - When we see an error in something we try to find a solution and searching about it I found several ways to solve it and it's listed, and I was wondering which one is the best one. I know that some of them might be good, others not that much and I wanted to know why.

Comment: @PeterSchneider - Exactly, now see the list about the best way to solve it.

Comment: I'm struggling to see what class `Bar` has to do with *any* of this. Your method doesn't return a value, and you're compiler should be wiped from your system if it doesn't [warn you of this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d38c987d4a9f4a5). As far as "best" way to handle it, treat the warning as an error, [such as this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd17835ea5d27b1c).

Comment: I didn't knew about the `-Wall` `-Werror`, thanks @WhozCraig.

Comment: @SH.0x90 I suspect this isn't going to live much longer, but its important none the less to note that you're essentially asking how to "best" handle a case of an *ill-formed* program. There is only one viable answer to that: *don't write ill-formed programs*. How you get there is quite literally a matter of taste and appropriateness for staying in lockstep with the goals of the program itself.

Comment: As WhozCraig mentioned, if you had treated warnings as errors, you never would have had the problem in the first place. I ran your program in a compiler that had the option set and *it refuses to compile in the first place*. Therefore, the *only* "best solution" is to return a default value.

Comment: As an aside: Note that you are not using `class Bar` but name your pointer `bar` which could be constructed as malicious in court ;-). The same crash would happen if you had a non virtual function and no inheritance hierarchy whatsoever. Indeed, it would happen with any freestanding (non-member) function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base class *does* implement the function, it just implements it wrong. It is not related to vtables or anything sophisticated. Solution 4 preferred (since it prevents building wrong programs), if not possible/desired 1 or 2 in that order.

Note that the error is not at all related to virtual functions, or inheritance in general (you do not use `Bar`, did you notice?). It is not even related to classes at all but would happen with any freestanding function as well. Consider:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Note: UB -- nothing returned
int getInt() {}
std::string getStr() {}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    // This probably works (read access from an arbitrary 
    // location on the stack which is in the prog's address space)
    std::cout << getInt() << std::endl;

    // This will crash. operator<< will try to access memory through
    // a pointer value which is some arbitrary byte pattern on the stack.
    // Probably not in the prog's address space.
    // Then the destructor for the temporary string will 
    // try to delete the same 
    // memory which will crash in any case, even if it happens to
    // point to valid memory (which, alas, was never allocated).
    std::cout << getStr();

    std::cout << "Still alive?\n"; // never printed
    std::cout.flush();

    return 0;
}
```

In order to prevent the error from happening with your original code, just return a value. If you implement the function and don't throw or abort (which are the three alternatives), i.e. if you return, you **must** return a value:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    virtual std::string myString() { return "test\n";}
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    Foo * bar = new Foo();
    std::cout << bar->myString();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you choose to return a default value? There are other ways to "solve" it.

Comment: @SH.0x90 the vtable is the classic implementation of polymorphism ofr today's compiler. According to C++, this is implementation dependant. There might compilers that could invent another technique not using vtable at all.

Comment: Well, if you are implementing it you must return a value, or throw, or abort. I just wanted to show that the crash happened because no string was where the caller expected one.

Answer (score 1):

The VTABLE is a table of pointers to virtual methods. In general, the pointer to the VTABLE is hidden from view, but it is often implemented as the first element in an instance of a class.

When a derived class does not have a member function that its parent class does implement as virtual, the parent's method will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Your `mystring` function should return a string.

Comment: Why did you choose to return a default value? There are other ways to "solve" it.

Comment: In what way you want this to work?
You can return some other value, which can call some other function and the likes. VTABLE, which you are asking is a completely different thing. VTABLE lookup happens when you declare a member function of the base class virtual implying, look in the parent class if a pointer of derived class is made with its memory allocated for the base class.

Comment: I don't want the base class with pure virtual because I want an instance of it, and other classes extends from that one and doesn't implement all the methods of the base, but we know that accidentally someone can call a method that isn't implemented and it needed to call the base's one.

Comment: Firstly, pure virtual returns has the notation of `=0`. A pure virtual function is required to be implemented by a derived class that is not abstract, which ofcourse, you are not doing. If you return anything, it doesn't become a pure virtual function. And secondly, if you are worried about the usages from derived class as accidents, you can make those functions private to the base class. Thirdly, you can still make an instance of the base class.